# clientHeight coming back as 0 when trying to get size of div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm really confused as to what is going on here. Basically, I have a div with the following setup:

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="maps">
      <h2>View marker
      </h2>
      <div class="the-contents" id="mapDiv123">ddddd</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code I need to grab the size of `mapDiv123` so I can then set the correct size for the Google Map going in. The SCSS looks like:

```
#test {
   background: pink;


    .maps {
       height: 350px;
       display: flex;

       flex-direction: column;
       background: orange;

       h2 {
         background: maroon;  
       }

      .the-contents {
          background: yellow;
          flex-grow: 2;
      }

    } 
}
```

The idea of this setup is that `.the-contents` will grow to fill the max space (minus the `h2`)

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/5nea3Lpj/

The weird part is that DOES work! Yet in my actual website, I get:

```
X: 0px (using window.getComputedStyle(maps).getPropertyValue("height"))
Y: 461.6px (using window.getComputedStyle(maps).getPropertyValue("width")) 
FOO 0 and 462 (using clientHeight and clientWidth)
```

I know the element is visible and I can see the dimensions when inspecting the element:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what else to try. Any ideas? (I can show people the problem site "in the real world", but its behind an IP firewall so you will need to message me with your IP so I can give you access to it)

Comment: Have you tried `getBoundingClientRect()` ? That's supposed to be the most accurate.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I hadn't - but it still seems to have the same problem :(  `bottom: 637.2333374023438,  height: 0, left: 285.5, right: 747.1000061035156, top: 637.2333374023438,
width: 461.6000061035156, x: 285.5, y: 637.2333374023438`

Comment: For X you get 0 by getting `(using window.getComputedStyle(maps).getPropertyValue("height"))`. But X axis is width, not height. Y axis is height

Comment: It seems to work in the jsfiddle just fine. Is the code on your website the same?

Comment: @Camille X and Y are not representative of the X and Y axis - they were just debug characters I used to know which line it matched up with :)

Comment: @MátéSafranka yeah thats the frustrating part! I thought I'd make up a fiddle to show the problem - and it bloomin worked there! The dev site is not publicly accessible (you would need to update your local hosts file to point to it)

Comment: AH MAN!!! I got it!!! I had this code AFTER it was grabbing the height:
  `hide_main_link_els(link_id);` . The layout basically has the original content, and then you click and icon to show the map with a marker. The map is hidden to start with, and then gets shown when they request it. Can't believe it was that stupid!!! I've been going around and around in circles with this for several hours :(

Comment: https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/373683012585549825

Comment: @MátéSafranka hahahahah so true!!!! (and always so simple when you see your mistake too!). Thanks everyone for walking through this with me. Sometimes it takes that to see your boo boo ;)

Comment: This is why a question should have a working code snippet, **reproducing** the issue described, and not just a code fragment.

Comment: @LGSon that was part of the problem - my sample code worked fine, but it didn't on the dev site. I was thinking it was maybe something to do with the fact it was a flex div, but now it seems not